# How to set the scale of the indcator?

Tags: pine-script

I have a pine script.
I would like to set the min and max value of axis.
Can you tell me how to set the min and max value of an axis of an indicator?
Is it possible?
Is it possible to set logarithmic scale for an indicator?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that's impossible. Only if you additionally handle the value in a way to restrict it's value or make it logarithmic. For example:

```
//@version=3
study("My Script")
plot(log(close))
```